# What's the derivative of $\int_0^x e^{t^2} dt$?

Tags: calculus

Let f be a continuous function on the interval $[a, b]$. The function F defined by

$$ \mathcal F(x) = \int_a^x f(t)dt $$

is continuous on $[a,b]$, differentiable on $(a,b)$ and has derivative

$$\mathcal F'(x) = \mathcal f(x)$$

My question is the following: What will happen in this case?

$$\mathcal H(x) = \int_0^x e^{t^2} dt$$

Would the derivative be:

$$\mathcal H'(x) = \mathcal e^{x^2}$$
or

$$\mathcal H'(x) = \mathcal e^{x^2}-1$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE; please proofread your question before posting, and use the [formatting guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to fix this.

Comment: Why would it be $\mathcal H'(x) = e^{x^2} - 1$? Where would the $-1$ come from?

Comment: $e^{t^2}$ you replace t with x - $e^{t^2}$ you replace t with 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we use the idea in your comment (to the question) then $\mathcal{F} '(x) $ should equal $f(x) - f(a) $ and not just $f(x) $ as mentioned in your question. I guess the confusion comes from mixing two parts of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (henceforth referred to as FTC).

Part 1 of FTC deals with an integral of the form $\int_{a} ^{x} f(t) \, dt$ where the lower limit of integral is a constant $a$ and upper limit $x$ is a variable. This then defines a new function, say $\mathcal{F} :[a, b] \to\mathbb{R} $ via the relation $$\mathcal {F} (x) =\int_{a} ^{x} f(t) \, dt\tag{1}$$ The goal of part 1 of FTC is to study the properties of this new function $\mathcal{F} $ in terms of properties of $f$. And *it says that $\mathcal{F} $ is continuous on $[a, b] $ and if $f$ is continuous at some $c\in[a, b] $ then $\mathcal{F} $ is differentiable at $c$ and $\mathcal{F} '(c) =f(c) $*.

You should notice that the lower limit $a$ does not figure out in conclusion of the theorem. The value $\mathcal{F} (x) $ depends on $f, a$ and $x$ but the value $\mathcal{F}' (x) $ depends on $f$ and $x$ only.

Part 2 of FTC deals with the evaluation of $\int_{a} ^{b} f(x) \, dx$ under certain conditions. *It assumes that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b] $ and possesses an anti-derivative $\mathcal{F} $ so that $$\mathcal{F} '(x) =f(x), \forall x\in[a, b] $$ and then says that* $$\int_{a} ^{b} f(x) \, dx=\mathcal{F} (b) - \mathcal {F} (a) \tag{2}$$ It is here that both the upper and lower limits of integration play key role and the integral is expressed as difference between the values of the anti-derivative.

Note that the $\mathcal{F} $ in both parts of FTC are different and in particular the $\mathcal{F} $ in part 1 is not necessarily an anti-derivative of $f$.

Comment: Very nce as usual! (+1)

Answer (score 4):

Note that $F(x+h)= F(x) + \int_x^{x+h} f(t)dt$ and for small $h$ we have $\int_x^{x+h} f(t)dt \approx \int_x^{x+h} f(x)dt = f(x) h$. Hence we expect $F'(x) = f(x)$.

It is straightforward to make this argument rigorous.

Comment: Very nice (+1).

Comment: You said for small $h$ we have $\int_x^{x+h} f(t)dt \approx \int_x^{x+h} f(x)dt = f(x) h$ why are you not getting rid of the h from the second integral and say something like this given that h is very small, approaching zero. $\int_x^{x+h} f(t)dt \approx \int_x^x f(x)dt = f(x) h$

Comment: @Ryk: You are trying to compute the limit as $h \to 0$ of ${F(x+h)-F(x) \over h}$. The above does is not divided across by $h$.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that in general by [**Leibniz integral rule**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) the following holds

$$F(x)=\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}g(u) du\implies F'(x)=g(b(x))\cdot b'(x)-g(a(x))\cdot a'(x)$$

therefore

$$\mathcal H(x) = \int_0^x e^{t^2} dt\implies \mathcal H'(x)=e^{x^2}$$

Comment: +1, very nice answer. I was not aware about Leibniz integral rule. Maybe I used it many times, but I was not aware that it was due to Leibniz.

Comment: @the_candyman Thanks, much appreciative! Bye

Comment: That's correct but I feel that's killing a bird with a bazooka. The OP has obviously problems with the application of a simple formula, why would a more general formula be helpful?

Comment: @Taladris Yes you are right but also I want to give a more general reference for more general cases.

Comment: +1: sometimes showing how to use nukes on a mosquito can still be beneficial for future readers!

Comment: @YiFan Exactly! I think that it is a important reference to keep in mind.All other answers are also very useful to give a full picture for the OP. Bye

Answer (score 1):

The simplest when applying a new formula is to identify each component:

> Let f be a continuous function on the interval $[a, b]$. The function F defined by
>
> $$F(x) = \int_a^x f(t)dt $$
>
> is continuous on $[a,b]$, differentiable on $(a,b)$ and has derivative
>
> $$F'(x) = \mathcal f(x)$$

For $H(x) = \int_0^x e^{t^2} dt$ we have $a=0$ (lower limit of integration) and $f(t)=e^{t^2}$.

It is also important to check that all conditions of the theorem are satisfied: here, the functions $g(t)=e^{t}$ and $h(t)=t^2$ are continuous on $\mathbb R$, so their composition $f=g\circ h$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$, hence on $[a,b]$.

Now, we can safely apply the formula: $H'(x) = f(x)=\mathcal e^{x^2}$.

---

**Edit**: to answer a comment

> What would happen if $a$ is not $0$?

Note that the formula depends only on $f$ and its continuity and not really on $a$. For example, consider $H_2(x)=\int_1^{x} f(t)\; dt= \int_1^x e^{t^2}\; dt$. Then, all of the above applies here and we have

$$H_2'(x) = f(x) = e^{x^2} $$

Wait! Why do the functions $H_2$ and $H_1(x)=\int^x_0 f(t)\; dt$ have the same derivative $f(x)=e^{x^2}$? That's clear when you remark that

$$H_1(x)=\int_0^x f(t)\; dt=\int_0^1 f(t)\; dt + \int_1^x f(t)\; dt= C + H_2(x)$$

where $C=\int_0^1 f(t)\; dt$. Since $C$ is a constant, we have $H_1'(x)=H_2'(x)$.

Comment: What happens when a is not zero then ?

Comment: Nice and simple approach! (+1)

Comment: @Ryk For the general case refer to the link I've given for Leibniz's rule.

Comment: Thank you, super approach! @Taladris

Comment: @gimusi, I will take a look into it, thank you!